# How to convert .avi video to .mp4(for Motorola Milestone, Android 2.3.4) with Avidemux

Tags: video, android, convert, mp4

I open .avi video with Avidemux and I set Video format to MPEG-4 AVC(under Configure, Bitrate tab I choose "Single Pass - Bitrate (Average)" and Target bitrate to 256 kb/s, under Filters I choose MPlayer resize to 480x360 and I also add a subtitles) audio format to AAC (Faac)(Under Configure, I choose Bitrate 96) and format to MP4(like a image below). When Avidemux convert video to .mp4 format I can play the file on my copmuter, but on my phone I can't. When I want to play it on my phone with native video player, it just show the error something like "Can't play this video". So the question is how to convert .avi video to .mp4 with Avidemux(because I want to have subtitles inside movie) to be playable with android phone(Android version 2.3.4) with native player.

Any help will be highly appreciated. :)

[image: Avidemux]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded **MoboPlayer** and **MoboPlayer Codec for ARMV7VFP3** from Android Market. It reads the .mp4 files and it also reads .avi(xvid) and .srt(subtitles), so I don't even need to convert the videos. If anyone can't play their videos on their Android phone, I suggest MoboPlayer(It's available from Android Market for free).

Answer (score 1):

Consider performing an interweb search for:

android video profiles

alternately an interweb search for:

android video formats

yielded
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

To convert AVI for playback on Motorola:

1. [Format Factory](http://format-factory.en.softonic.com/): is free and easy-to-use.
2. [Third-Party software](http://www.faasoft.com/articles/how-to-play-avi-on-android.html), recommend one them which i tried.

Answer (score -2):

Motorola Razr M HD should have bulit in player support playing videos in these formats: MP4/3GP. Unfortunately, your M4a (or M4V maybe) videos are not compatible with Motorola Razr M HD.

So, first step, you need to use Motorola video converter for Mac to convert videos to MP4.

Final step is dragging and dropping converted AVI videos to your Android phone Motorola Razr M HD.